# Similar idioms to "beat me to it"?

Tags: idioms

I googled a bit but didn't find anything similar to it. Are there other similar idioms to "beat me to it"? For example I’ve often heard it’s used when someone does something first before you, then you would say that.

Comment: Can you add details on what specific context you'd use this in? Otherwise it could be a duplicate of any number of questions, such as [Proverb for when one person sees something, but someone else takes it](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/470563/191178).

Comment: In business context, you may say **first to market**. Sony’s Walkman was a great success because Sony were first to market in the personal stereo field.

Answer (score 3):

She **pipped me to the post**.

> [PHRASE] [British, informal] If someone is *pipped at the post* or
> pipped to the post they are just beaten in a competition or in a race
> to achieve something. [British, informal]

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-pip-someone-at-the-post)]

> To defeat or succeed over someone by a very narrow margin or at the
> final, crucial moment, especially in a race

[[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pip+at+the+post)]

> ... EU number one supplier of COVID-19 vaccines to the world ...
> anyone else ... we were pipped at the post by Israel, but we are not
> far behind

[[Amateur Photographer!](https://www.amateurphotographer.co.uk/forums/threads/covid-vaccine.142244/page-40)]

Answer (score 2):

**beat (someone) to the punch** (idiom)

> To do or achieve something before someone else is able to
>
> *We were working on a new product but before we could get it into the market our competition beat us to the punch.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beat%20someone%20to%20the%20punch)

Related, but more for gaining an advantage than for winning:

**get the drop on (someone or something)**

> To acquire an advantage over another person or entity; to catch someone or something in a vulnerable position or situation. The phrase refers to drawing a gun on someone first (thus causing them to "drop" their own gun).
>
> *I think we'll get the drop on the defense if we run this play next.*
>
> *The police received an anonymous tip and got the drop on the would-be robbers when they entered the bank.* [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+the+drop+on+(someone+or+something))